# How do I decompress this on golang?

Tags: c#, go, compression, zlib

I'm trying to port some C# code to Golang, so let's assume that I have this C# code that compress some bytes:

```cs
        public byte[] Compress(byte[] input, int outputSize)
        {
            ZStream zStream = new ZStream();
            zStream.deflateInit(zlibConst.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, -15);
            byte[] output = new byte[outputSize];

            zStream.next_in = input;
            zStream.next_in_index = 0;
            zStream.avail_in = input.Length;
            zStream.next_out = output;
            zStream.next_out_index = 0;
            zStream.avail_out = output.Length;

            var ret = zStream.deflate(zlibConst.Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
            if (ret != zlibConst.Z_OK)
            {
                throw new Exception($"[NetworkMessage.PrepareToParse] zlib inflate failed: {ret}");
            }
            return output;

        }
```

How can I decompress these bytes using Golang?

I assumed that would be easy, using `compress/flate` or `compress/zlib`, writing something like this:

```golang
func Decompress(input []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    r := flate.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(input))
    decompressed, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return decompressed, nil
}
```

But this is leading to a `unexpected EOF`, and `compress/zlib` led to `zlib: invalid header`, which I guess it makes sense since it's not a full zlib stream.

Comment: Can you provide a sample compressed and original data? Best would be using a slice literal like `input = []byte{...}` so we can try it right away.

Answer (score 0):

`flate` will work. Your problem is on the compress side. `flate` is reporting an unexpected end of stream because you didn't end it. You need to use `Z_FINISH`, not `Z_SYNC_FLUSH`.